# Lanching application and transition speed, fluidity

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, phonegap-build, transition, launching-application

I just built my mobile application using JQM and Phonegap Build and I have two questions:

1. I have a script to run at startup of the application that uses autologin, however on the first page after the splashscreen, you see the page appear and immediately you have redirect on the second page. I do not want to see this page I would like to show that during the splashscreen my script and am reading it is immediately on the second page. I already try with the event `mobile init`, `beforepagecreate` but my script is not even read.
2. How can I improve the responsiveness and smoothness of transitions between pages? I have used the Closure Compiler Service from Google, I also followed the advice on a website that said to place all calls to scripts and libraries at the end of page (front). It's already gaining speed but still not enough.

Comment: use `pagebeforechange` not `pagebeforecreate`.

Comment: i have the same probleme with pagebeforechange

Comment: This CSS controls the speed of JQM transitions  --- .in, .out {
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 350ms !important;
}

Comment: Yeahh thanks Tasos, 50ms its perfect, but what the minimal value for animation-duration without bug ?   So, the problem number 2 is resolved, thanks

Comment: I try with 10ms for page-pre-in/out and 50ms for slide-in/out and its ok for the moment